# add orderby clause when fetching data from parse.com

Tags: php, curl, parse-platform

I am tryng to fetch data from parse.com but its not allow to skip more than 10000 data so for doing it in a alternate way i have to use order by

My code is

```
$request = 'skip='.$max.'&limit=1000';

$url = "https://api.parse.com/1/classes/_Installation" . "?".$request;
// $ch = curl_init($url); 
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  
$response = curl_exec($ch);  

$parse_data=json_decode($response,true);
```

I'm trying to use this concept https://www.parse.com/questions/paging-through-more-than-10000-results

but i don't know how to use orderby in `curl` code.

please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [API docs](https://parse.com/docs/rest#installations) say:

> You can sort by multiple fields by passing order a comma-separated
>   list. To retrieve documents that are ordered by scores in ascending
>   order and the names in descending order:

Example for you:

```
$request = 'skip='.$max.'&limit=1000&order=your_order_field';
```

You can choose if order should be ascending or descending by adding `-`:

```
$request = 'skip='.$max.'&limit=1000&order=your_order_field';//ASC
$request = 'skip='.$max.'&limit=1000&order=-your_order_field';//DESC
```

Comment: thanks for the solution. it worked. can you tell me how to add where condition in it ??

Comment: Yes, you can add `where={"your_field":{"$gte":1000}}` like `$request = 'skip='.$max.'&limit=1000&order=-your_order_field&where={"your_field":{"$gte":1000}}';`. List of available operators is available here https://parse.com/docs/rest#installations

Comment: [Paul](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2775748/paul-tomkiel) when i am doing this its not working - skip=0&limit=1000&order=createdAt&where={"createdAt":{"$gte":'.$last_created.'}}';  my last created format is like this $last_created='2014-07-08T06:56:59.000Z';

Comment: Ok [Paul](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2775748/paul-tomkiel) i found a solution for this. thanks a lot.